# Python Pandas ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, valueerror

The following is my dataframe `temp`

| aadt | fs | speed_limit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5580 | 3 | 0 |
| 0 | 7 | 0 |
| 1750 | 3 | 10 |
| 0 | 7 | 0 |
| 3940 | 4 | 0 |
| 470 | 5 | 0 |
| 0 | 7 | 0 |
| 0 | 7 | 0 |

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'aadt'       : [5580, 0, 1750, 0, 3940, 470, 0, 0],
    'fc'         : [3, 7, 3, 7, 4, 5, 7, 7],
    'speed_limit': [0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
})
```

I'm trying to replace the zeros in speed_limit column with a function of 'fs' column. The function is `38 + temp['fs']`. However, `speed_limit` can take only certain values from `mylist`.

The following code works well without `temp['fs']`. However, adding `temp['fs']` raises the ValueError. Any suggestions are welcome.

```
myList = [15, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 60, 70]

temp['speed_limit'] = np.where(
    temp['speed_limit']==0
    ,min(filter(lambda i: i > (38 + temp['fs']), myList))
    ,temp['speed_limit'])
```

Comment: `temp['speed_limit']==0` This comparison makes no sense.  `temp['speed_limit']` is a _column_ containing many values.  Some are equal to zero and some aren't.  It makes no sense to ask "is this column equal to zero".

Comment: @JohnGordon. No it makes sense. The problem is the `filter` part